# PHP - exclude file type when printing img directory

Tags: php, foreach, glob, file-type, scandir

I am writing a simple fishing game in PHP. I have a snippet of code that's printing all of the image files in my /img directory, but it's also outputting **.DS_Store**. I want to exclude that file, maybe using glob(), but I don't know how. I've googled this for hours with no luck.

```
$files = scandir('img');
if ($files !== false) {
    foreach($files as $f) {
        if ($f == '..' || $f == '.') continue;
            echo '<li class="fish_pic"><img src="img/'.$f.'" alt="'.$f.'" title="" class="fish"></li>'."\n";
    }
}
```

How can I exclude .DS_Store?

Comment: Please learn to indent your code so that it's readable and blocks/nesting are clear.

Comment: As I'm new here, could you please tell me how to properly indent my code? Tab doesn't work. And instead of downvoting, maybe teach new users so they can learn.

Comment: Indented. Could you remove the downvote?

Comment: Done. BTW, the echo should not be indented, as it's not nested under the 'if'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = scandir('img');
if ($files !== false) {
    foreach($files as $f) {
        if ($f == '..' || $f == '.' || substr($f, -strlen(".DS_Store")) === ".DS_Store") continue;
            echo '<li class="fish_pic"><img src="img/'.$f.'" alt="'.$f.'" title="" class="fish"></li>'."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an if rule.

```
if ($f == '..' || $f == '.' || $f == '.DS_Store') continue;
```

Alternatively, you could use an array and [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array) method.

```
$filesToSkip = array('.', '..', '.DS_Store', 'other_file_to_skip');

$files = scandir('img');
if ($files !== false) {
 foreach($files as $f) {
   if (in_array($f, $filesToSkip)) continue;
   echo '<li class="fish_pic"><img src="img/'.$f.'" alt="'.$f.'" title="" class="fish">   </li>'."\n";
 }
}
```